# Logback in maven project

Tags: java, maven, logback

I found two ways to use Logback library in maven project and I don't understand the difference;

1. in pom file:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. in config xml file:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    .
    .
    .
</configuration>
```

so is there a difference in the way of fetching the jar or something or both are the same thing?

Comment: The first one is defining the dependency in the Maven POM, and the second one is the actual Logback configuration file. They are two completely distinct usecases.

Comment: yes but both are in two different projects, and in the second one I didn't find dependency for the logback although I found it's usage in the code.

Comment: The second one seems to be a Spring Boot project, where Spring Boot brings in Logback as a transitive dependency, so that's why it is not explicitly defined in the pom.xml

Comment: is there a best practice in this or both ways are fine,, cause the first was a spring boot project too?

Comment: Then it was just unnecessary to specify the dependency explicityl. But again, your second example is the logback configuration file, it doesn't have any effect on Maven, and you need to include the dependency in Maven, either explicitly or through another library, which brings it in.